# Pass the url to the jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

function open(url) {
    $('#blockdiv').fadeIn();
    $('#iframe').attr('src', url);
    $('#containerdiv').fadeIn();   
}

function close() {  
    $('#blockdiv').fadeOut();
    $('#containerdiv').fadeOut();  
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul').css({width: $('#containerdiv').width(),height:$('#containerdiv').height()})
     $('#close').click( function() { close() })
     $('#nj_apply').click( function() { open('http://www.yahoo.com/') })

});

</script>

<td>
<input id= "nj_apply" type=button value="Apply" >
</td>
```

In the above code, url `(http://www.yahoo.com/)` is hardcoded in the script tag. But I want to pass the url to the above jquery function from the input tag itself. Whenever I click on apply button it should pass the url to the above jQuery function.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: I answered, but didn't notice you only had a button, and not a text input.  Does that mean they don't actually enter the url?  Its hardcoded into the button?  If so, I will revise my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `data-...` attribute and jQuery `data` method:

```
function open(url) {
    $('#blockdiv').fadeIn();
    $('#iframe').attr('src', url);
    $('#containerdiv').fadeIn();   
}

function close() {  
    $('#blockdiv').fadeOut();
    $('#containerdiv').fadeOut();  
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul').css({width: $('#containerdiv').width(),height:$('#containerdiv').height()})
     $('#close').click( function() { close() })
     $('#nj_apply').click( function() { open($(this).data('url')); })

});

</script>

<td>
<input id= "nj_apply" type=button value="Apply" data-url="http://www.yahoo.com/">
</td>
```

Comment: I think he wants the field to be entered by the user, so he wants the 'value' of the input, not another hardcoded url as a data attribute

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible....

This uses `onblur`, and  will read the value entered by a user, as soon as he clicks off the box....then pass that vlue to the function...

Or you could do `onkeyup`, or `change`, to have it execute as the user types.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul').css({width: $('#containerdiv').width(),height:$('#containerdiv').height()})
 $('#close').click( function() { close() })

 $('#nj_apply').onblur( function() { 
   var url =  $(this).val();
   open(url); })

 });

 </script>

<td>
<input id= "nj_apply" type="text" />
</td>
```

The above way you don't even have to click any button, it will automatically execute, onblur....but if you wanna have to click a button, do it like this....

In your javascript...

```
$('#applytheurl').click( function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
 var url =  $("#nj_apply").val();
  open(url); })
 });
```

Your HTML...

```
 <td>
<input id= "nj_apply" type="text" />
<button id="applytheurl">GET PAGE</button>
</td>
```

**EDIT**

I may have misunderstood what you wanted.....

This answer below, is if you plan to have multiple buttons, each going to a different page.....

Your HTML...

```
<td>
<input class="geturl" type="button" value="Apply" data-url="www.test.com" />
<input class="geturl" type="button" value="Apply" data-url="www.test2.com" />
<input class="geturl" type="button" value="Apply" data-url="www.test3.com" />
<input class="geturl" type="button" value="Apply" data-url="www.test4.com" />
</td>
```

Your javascript...

```
$('.geturl').click( function(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); 
 var url =  $(this).data('url');
 open(url); })
 });
```

Comment: onkeyup or onkeypress on button? :)

Comment: Oh shit...I didn't notice he only has a button, I thought he had a text input field....now Im confused...

Comment: maybe he have couple of buttons and don't want to duplicate code